# Modifier disappears from render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I can't figure out why my modifiers sometimes stop rendering, and it apparently happens with both Cycles and Eevee. I'm using VertexWeightProximity together with UVWarp to change the transmission of the shader. It renders fine in the render view, it renders fine in render window. But I don't know what I do (if it's something I do), after I apply this to a couple of objects, I apply it to a new one and now it renders only in the render view, but not in the render window. And I swear I have the modifiers active for both render and viewport. See below: render view has this transparent line on the left, render window is all plain.

[image]

What could be happening? Could it be some name conflict (all modifiers, vertex groups, UV maps, etc. have the same names, although they belong to different objects)? Memory issues? Just a bug?

EDIT: A simpler setup, but that shows the same effect (plus modifiers getting borked in the viewport and needing to be re-toggled in order to be fixed): https://paste.c-net.org/SandyCruelest

EDIT 2: I think it must be a bug or a limitation (https://developer.blender.org/T92336), and it happens because object A has a modifier that depends on object B, and object B has a modifier that depends on object A. A workaround is creating a linked (and parented) duplicate of e.g. object A, so object B can reference the duplicate instead.

Comment: I don't see an appreciable difference in distance.blend (provided) between Eevee render and preview?  Maybe point out the difference in images so people can reproduce your problem?  But it's likely to be due to the different render and preview settings (iterations) on your subdivision modifiers.

Comment: After reviewing your bug report, the issue is a dependency loop.  I've commented there.